# GetAsyncKeystate not found in user32.dll

Tags: c#

I just started with c# and trying around with things right now. I searched for a color aimbot because I wanted to find out how it work and I made a code by my own. But when I start it I get the message that `GetAsyncKeystate` is not found in my `user32.dll`.

The code has no error and is perfect

```
return GetAsyncKeystate(vkey) < 0;
```

That is the code where I get this error:

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: "Der Einstiegspunkt "GetAsyncKeystate" wurde nicht in der DLL "user32.dll" gefunden

Comment: Provide your GetAsyncKeyState extern method declaration

Comment: `GetAsyncKeystate()` != `GetAsyncKeyState()`